# examples where $g$ is a strictly increasing function on an interval say $J$ but $g$ is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I am reading *Elementary Analysis The theory of Calculus* by Kenneth A Ross.

Theorem 18.5 Page 130 says

Let $g$ be a strictly increasing function on an interval $J$ such that $g(J)$ is an interval $I$. Then $g$ is continuous on $J$.

I want to construct some examples where $g$ is a strictly increasing function on an interval say $J$ but $g$ is not continuous.  I am trying to see and appreciate why "$g(J)$ is an interval"  is necessary here.

I have constructed some examples by drawing graphs but I want to know some concrete examples.

Thanks.

Comment: In words: if $g$ is strictly increasing on an interval $J$ and not continuous then $g$ "is forced" to make a "jump going upwards" somewhere (this because some point $x\in J$ must exist where $g$ is not continuous). That jump takes away the possibility that the image of $g$ is also an interval. It splits up the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=x$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $\geq 0$ is such a  function.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be a bijection from $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ to $\Bbb N$. Let $g$ be defined on $[0,1]$ by

$$g(x)=\sum_{q\le x} 2^{-k(q)}$$

Where the sum runs on rational $q$ in $[0,x)$.

This function is strictly increasing, continuous at irrational $x$ and discontinuous at rational $x$.